# Diameter of a graph given the Independence number

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove that the diameter of an undirected simple graph is at most 3 if its independence number equals 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the diameter is larger than 3, say 4. then we get a path on 5 vertices, which is a shortest path connecting its endpoints. Hence the endpoints and the vertex in the middle are not adjacent whatsoever. We have found an independent set of size three. A contradiction.